# WPF // MahApps.Metro // Caliburn.Micro // Flyout // HeaderedContentControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

Since a change in MahApps.Metro 1.5.0 the base element of a Flyout was changed from `ContentControl` to `HeaderContentControl`. Now the MVVM approach with Caliburn.Micro and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23206251/3414767) suggestion doesn't work anymore.

Has anybody else tried to solve this issue in a nice MVVM way?

Comment: See the following link: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2953

Comment: I will join there (and update here with an answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it myself but since the new `Flyout` control is now based on `HeaderedContentControl` it would be a simple logic choice to attempt to do this instead of the previous, which was based on `ContentControl`. Looks like the advantages of this change were the elimination of a couple of dependency properties...

```
<controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <HeaderedContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The other thing that might come out of this that you create a Caliburn.micro convention to actually bind correctly to that `HeaderedContentControl` which wouldn't be all that different from the `ContentControl` variant was, by default in CM already.  What is odd is that this `HeaderedContentControl` is derived from `ContentControl` in theory it should have been found correctly.  Another thing to think about is this actually might also be related to Visual Tree where CM can't see it till it's in the tree, therefore can't bind it.

[Content Control convention in CM source](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs#L320) as a reference.

Comment: It isn't working with the changed ItemTemplate. The header is set to "Cannot find view for System.String." and the content shows the ViewModel.ToString() property (but with Snoop I can see that the DataContext is correctly set).

Answer (score 0):

I've added posted a work around [on GitHub](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/451#issuecomment-308348654).

It appears there's something going on with setting the `ItemTemplate` of the `FlyoutsControl`.