# Mahapps Flyout content not showing with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I chose to use Caliburn.Micro since open/close flyout was a challenge from a viewmodel. I have a challenge to display content from a second flyout and it shows only the header.

I had tried every suggestion I could find in the net, please also refer
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2953

Has anyone experienced the same issue and solved it?

Thanks and Appreciate your effort.

Cheers

Comment: Another thread regarding this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735278/wpf-mahapps-metro-caliburn-micro-flyout-headeredcontentcontrol).

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn micro author just released new comments on https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2953

Basically it's a Mahapps bug , but VM author provides a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, been following that thread and acknowledged it too. The workaround fixes the issue.